# Widget toggle functionality with $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to implement toggle functionality for the widget. When the user clicks on the minimization button then widget should shrink and expand when click on maximize button respectively.

[image: Widget]

[image: widget]

I'm trying to achieve this functionality with below piece of code.
Functionality working as expected but it is registering the event multiple times(I'm emitting the event and catching in the filterTemplate directive).

**How can we stop registering the event multiple times  ?**

Or
 **Is there anyway to like compiling once and on toggle button bind the template/directive to DOM and to make it work rest of the functionality .**

So could you please help me to fix this.

```
function bindFilterTemplate(minimize) {
    if ($scope.item && !minimize) {
        if ($scope.item.filterTemplate) { // filter template is  custom 
                                          // directive like this
                                          // "<widget></widget>"
            $timeout(function () {
                var filterElement = angular.element($scope.item.filterTemplate);
                var filterBody = element.find('.cls-filter-body');
                filterElement.appendTo(filterBody);
                $compile(filterElement)($scope); // Compiling with
                     // current scope on  every time when user click on
                     // the minimization button.
            });
        }
    } else {
        $timeout(function () {
            element.find('.cls-filter-body').empty();
        });
    }
}
bindFilterTemplate();
```

```
// Directive
app.directive('widget', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'widgetController',
        link: function ($scope, elem) {
            // Some code
        }
    };
});


// Controller
app.controller('widgetController', function ($scope) {

    // This event emitting from parent directive
    // On every compile, the event is registering with scope.
    // So it is triggering multiple times.
    $scope.$on('evt.filer', function ($evt) {
        // Server call
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you show us your directive code where exactly you're binding event and how?

Comment: @Pankaj Parkar  Updated code.

Comment: Could you please check

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue, but didn't succeed, you can look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jDjBAyzs1DJcBNDRelyf?p=preview)(this is what I have tried)

Comment: Everytime one uses the $compile compile service, it adds watchers to scope. Instead, consider using the [ng-show / ng-hide directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) to toggle visibility of DOM elements.

Comment: @ georgeawg
Could you please check below solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by creating new scope with `$scope.$new()`.

When user minimizes the widget destroying the scope.

Please let me know if you have any other solution to fix this.

```
 function bindFilterTemplate(minimize) {
        // Creating the new scope.
        $scope.newChildScope = $scope.$new();
        if ($scope.item && !minimize) {
          if ($scope.item.filterTemplate) {
            $timeout(function () {
              var filterElement = angular.element($scope.item.filterTemplate);
              var filterBody = element.find('.cls-filter-body');
              filterElement.appendTo(filterBody);
              $compile(filterElement)($scope.newChildScope);
            });
          }
        } else {
          $timeout(function () {
            if ($scope.newChildScope) {
              // Destroying the new scope
              $scope.newChildScope.$destroy();
            }
            element.find('.cls-filter-body').empty();
          });
        }
      }
```